# Search in CRS window doesn't show any results

Tags: qgis, mac

I'm using an iMac with OS 12.3. I've been using QGIS for a while, but it stopped working correctly two days ago. There are two problems:

1. The Hillshade function won't run from Raster > Analysis > Hillshade, but it sometimes works from the Processing Toolbox.
2. When I'm in the CRS window and enter anything in the search field (such as utah state plane), there are no results. Only about 6 CRSs are available, no matter what I search for.

I've reinstalled QGIS several times, both the latest and LTR versions, but no change. I have version 3.22 on my MacBook, and it works correctly. I need it to work on my iMac, and have no idea why it suddenly stopped working properly. I don't know what else I can try. BTW, the QGIS download page says the LTR is 3.28, but when I installed it, it was version 3.34.